# equally divide css flex colums in container (vertical)

Tags: css

I want to show the uptime/downtime of my website with a div containing vertical bars (red, green or no color when no data).

The css for this:

```
 .lines {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  background: #eee;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.lines > .line {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  height: 100%;
  border: 0.5px solid #ccc;
}

.line:not(:first-child) {
  border-left: 0;
}

.lines > .line.true {
  background: greenyellow;
}

.lines > .line.false {
  background: red;
}
```

This gives me the following result with my data:
[image]
As you can see, the "colums" (divs) are not equally separated, even though I use `flex: 1 1 auto`).

JS:

```
<div className={styles.lines>
  {data.map((e,i) => (
    <div key={i} className={`${styles.line} ${e.bool === 'true' ? styles.true : styles.false}`} />
  )}
</div>
```

Where is my code wrong?

Comment: Please add the generated html instead, you just need to add enough to create a simplified example. By looking at the code, it is possible because you set the .line to flex-shrink: 1 instead of 0

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a rendering issue, because some lines get truncated as they're less than 1 pixel. The following should solve the issue:

```
.lines > .line {
  ...
  min-width: 1px;
}
```

Also note that borders need to be at least 1 pixel, 0.5 px will simply default to 1px.